# Supervisor [program:x] Section exitcode

Tags: supervisord

I'm trying to configure and understand the supervisord program section. One option stated in the manual is `exitcodes`

```
exitcodes

The list of “expected” exit codes for this program. 
If the autorestart parameter is set to unexpected, 
and the process exits in any other way than as a 
result of a supervisor stop request, supervisord 
will restart the process if it exits with an exit 
code that is not defined in this list.

Default: 0,2

Required: No.

Introduced: 3.0
```

Where can I find a reference for each available exit codes?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101957/are-there-any-standard-exit-status-codes-in-linux

Comment: thanks a bunch @daniula..a link consist of link to another link to another link..really like a error list codes..unlimited number